# Tree data in MySql database table

Tags: mysql, triggers, hierarchical-data

I have a table that uses Adjacency list model for hierarchy storage. My most relevant columns in this table are therefore:

```
ItemId // is auto_increment
ParentId
Level
ParentTrail // in the form of "parentId/../parentId/itemId"
```

then I created a before insert tigger, that populates columns `Level` and `ParentTrail`. Since  the last column also includes current item's ID I had to use a trick in my trigger because `auto_increment` columns are not available in the before insert trigger. So I get that value from the `information_schema.tables` table.

All works fine, until I try to write an update trigger, that would update my item and its descendants when the item changes its parent (`ParentId` has changed). But I can't make an update on my table inside the update trigger. All I can do is to change current record's values but not other's.

I could use a separate table for hierarchy data, but that would mean that I would also have to create a view that would combine these two tables (1:1 relation) and I would like to avoid this is at all possible.

**Is there a way to have all these in the same table so that these fields (`Level` and `ParetTrail`) set/update themselves automagically using triggers?**

Comment: What's so bad about creating a separate table for hierarchy data?  It sounds completely appropriate.

Comment: Because I would like to use Entity Framework with MySQL. Having two tables would force me to create a View and map it to my Entity class. Updating entity instances (or creating new ones) wouldn't be possible. I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it might be possible, but it would involve some heavy string matching etc. Wouldn't want to dig myself into it.

If you are willing to change your database model slightly and implement a [Nested Set](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) (scroll down on the page) this could probably be done easily by having the trigger update left-right values.